# How to implement an signalr CLIENT in c# System.Web.Http.ApiController

Tags: c#, signalr, mqtt, publish-subscribe

We have an application running different services (c#, .NET Core) LOCAL on a Windows PC.

I now need some kind of mechanism to inform all interested services if data changed in one service (some kind of observer pattern for microservices, or some kind of MQTT (pub/sub) mechanism of c# and .NET Core microservices locally running on a windows pc).

First I want to use Sockets but the Windows documentation says use Signalr instead.

So here is what I have so far:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
        // empty
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add services.

        //Test bidirectional communication (pub / sub Pattern over SignalR groups)
        services.AddSignalR();

        // Add the localization services to the services container.
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Properties");

        services.AddMvc()
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Use sessions
        // The order of middleware is important. 
        // An InvalidOperationException exception will occur when UseSession is invoked after UseMvc.
        app.UseSession();

        //Test bidirectional communication (pub / sub Pattern over SignalR groups)
        //The SignalR Hubs API enables you to call methods on connected clients from the server.
        //In the server code, you define methods that are called by client. In the client code, you define methods that are called from the server.
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/SignalRHub");
        });

        app.UseMvc(
            routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
    }
}
```

For the .NET CORE Service
But I now need a client for the c# `System.Web.Http.ApiController` and can not find an example.

Seems some are confused by our "beautiful" architecture ;-) 
I hope the following picture makes it clearer:
[image: Architecture overview]

So, if Application 1 changes data in Microservice 2, than Application 2 has to be informed.
And again, this is all running local on a Windows PC, no clouds are involved.

Comment: SignalR is not a message bus. Look into something like RabbitMQ instead.

Comment: Yes, that's obviously the best solution. And I recommend you to take a look at the [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/) library

Comment: I looked at RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) but I do not wannt to install anything, because than we have to provide it with the installation of the application (nuget packages are ok). Seems like i have to implement an socket observer by my own.

Comment: If you don't want to install anything, you can look into a hosted solution such as [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) or [CloudAMQP](https://www.cloudamqp.com/) (RabbitMQ As A Service).

Comment: @mason I do not think this is running local on an PC, or? I need a local PC solution.

Comment: Why must it be a local PC solution? And if it's a local PC solution, then why don't you want to install anything?

Answer (score 2):

Probably missing something from your description. 
SignalR is fine if there are clients to report relevant information to. 
In your scenario, however, it would seem that the clients are the APIs themselves and this makes little sense to me. 
Maybe there's a piece missing in the middle that does the work you're saying.

In any case, you may find relevant technical information about SignalR starting from the official website.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio